# How to put cursor on the end of TextField in ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a field where users can edit data. I use `focus()` to place cursor directly to appropriate `TextField`. However it is always positioned in the beginning of word.

This is how I do it:

```
  xtype: 'textfield',
  value: record ? record.get('value') : '',
  listeners: {
    afterrender: function(field) {
      field.focus(false);
    }
  }
```

Is there a way how to put cursor on the end of existing word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get the same result if you change the selection region to the end of the textfield. Use `setSelectionRange()`to do it. You could do it like this:

```
xtype: 'textfield',
value: record ? record.get('value') : '',
listeners: {
    afterrender: function(field) {
        field.focus(false);
        var len = field.value.length;
        field.inputEl.dom.setSelectionRange(len,len);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding `field.selectionStart = field.selectionEnd` should do the trick.

```
xtype: 'textfield',
value: record ? record.get('value') : '',
listeners: {
    afterrender: function(field) {
        field.focus(false);
        field.selectionStart = field.selectionEnd;
    }
}
```